# {fmt}: How to pass a wrapped iterator to formatter

Tags: c++, iterator, fmt

I'm playing with the C++ [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library, specifically with making a simple repr wrapper that converts the object representation into printable one (characters like '\n', '\x02', etc. are converted to "\n", "\x02", ...). While there is already a [library](https://github.com/p-ranav/repr) with a feature simular to this, i don't like the idea of creating temporary string buffers just to store the formatted replacement field there, converting characters in it and destroying it after:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <iterator>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>


template <typename T>
concept Formattable = fmt::has_formatter<T, fmt::format_context>::value;

template <typename T> requires Formattable<T>
struct Repr
{
    const T& t;
    
    explicit Repr(const T& t) : t(t)
    {}
};

template <typename OutputIt>
struct repr_adapter
{
    OutputIt& it;

    explicit repr_adapter(OutputIt& it) : it(it)
    {}

    repr_adapter& operator=(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '\a':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'a';
            break;
        case '\b':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'b';
            break;
        case '\x1b':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'e';
            break;
        case '\f':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'f';
            break;
        case '\n':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'n';
            break;
        case '\r':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'r';
            break;
        case '\t':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 't';
            break;
        case '\v':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = 'v';
            break;
        case '\\':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = '\\';
            break;
        case '\'':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = '\'';
            break;
        case '\"':
            *it++ = '\\';
            *it++ = '\"';
            break;
        default:
            if (' ' <= c && c <= '~')
                *it++ = c;
            else
                it = fmt::format_to(it, "\\x{:02x}", c);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename OutputIt>
struct repr_iterator : std::iterator_traits<OutputIt>
{
    // Is a pointer so that it's copyable
    OutputIt* iterator;

    repr_iterator(OutputIt& iterator) : iterator(&iterator)
    {}

    repr_adapter<OutputIt> operator*()
    {
        return repr_adapter<OutputIt>{*iterator};
    }
    repr_iterator& operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    repr_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

// Actually important code starts here
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<Repr<T>> : public fmt::formatter<T>
{
    using fmt::formatter<T>::parse;

    template<typename FormatContext>
    auto format(Repr<T> repr, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        // Working version (but does not actually modify format output)
        return fmt::formatter<T>::format(repr.t, ctx);
    }
};

int main()
{
    fmt::print("{}\n", Repr<const char*>{"abc\ndef"});
}
```

I've been almost succesful, by making a flimsy output iterator wrapper and using the default format:

```
template<typename FormatContext>
auto format(Repr<T> repr, FormatContext& ctx)
{
    // Working version (converts \n and stuff but uses the default format,
    // ignores the specifier parse result)
    auto it = ctx.out();
    repr_iterator<decltype(it)> repr_it{ it };
    fmt::format_to(repr_it, "{}", repr.t);
    return *repr_it.iterator;
}
```

, but the problem is that to call the wrapped `formatter<T>::format`(that uses the parsed specifiers) i need to somehow create instance of `fmt::basic_format_context` with my wrapping `repr_iterator` from the `FormatContext` i'm being passed in the wrapping formatter:

```
auto format(Repr<T> repr, FormatContext& ctx)
{
    // Does not work
    auto it = ctx.out();
    repr_iterator<decltype(it)> repr_it{ &it };
    return fmt::formatter<T>::format(
        repr.t,
        fmt::basic_format_context<decltype(repr_it), char>{
            repr_it,
            ctx.args(),
            ctx.locale()
        }
    );
}
```

which does not work and produces an error that, if i understand it correctly, rightfully complains that the `basic_format_args<basic_format_context<..., [...]>>` is not convertible to `basic_format_args<basic_format_context<repr_iterator<...>, [...]>>`, because everything in fmt is tied to the format context (the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/njzY7Msd1) with full error). Is there a way to do this via the iterator wrapper, or am i doomed to use the std::string as the intermediate formatting value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can swap the iterator type like that and having such an iterator adapter is unlikely to be beneficial performance-wise. You would be much better off writing to an intermediate buffer and then doing the transformation when copying from the buffer to the output iterator. Unlike the adapter approach this can be easily optimized for the common case of contiguous iterators.